# SVG <set> tag's dur attribute does not animate

Tags: css, svg, w3c

I'm trying to animate a rollover using the SVG `<set>` tag, but even though I specify dur="1s", the transition is instantaneous (in Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome).

```
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red">
        <set attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="green" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout" dur="1s" />
    </circle>
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

I can achieve the effect that I want using two `<animate>` tags, but I want to be able to apply the transition to multiple elements that may have different initial colors that I want preserved (this method requires that I specify the initial color "red" in the second animate tag).

```
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red">
        <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="green" begin="mouseover" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="red" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
    </circle>
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

The `<set>` tag in the first code segment preserves the initial colors, but the transition is not animated. If my understanding of the w3 spec is correct, it should be - does this look like a browser-specific bug, or did I misunderstand the w3 spec? Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: Repro cases: http://jsfiddle.net/4xx5p/ (and this is true on Safari as well as Firefox)

Comment: Thanks for verifying that it doesn't work in Safari either; I just tested in Opera and Chrome as well, and I'm getting the same behavior there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [SVG 1.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#SetElement):

> The ‘set’ element provides a simple means of **just setting** the value of an attribute **for a specified duration**.
>   …
>   `to = "<value>"` Specifies the value for the attribute **during the duration of the ‘set’ element**.

(Emphasis mine.)

As you can see, the `duration` of the `<set>` element is not a transition time, but rather how long the effect is to be applied. If you remove the `end` attribute you'll see the color change from red to green for 1 second [and then revert](http://jsfiddle.net/4xx5p/1/) to the original value.

For more details, read about the `<set>` element in the [SMIL Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#setElement).

---

**Edit**: Here's an example of using custom data to annotate your SVG elements and a run-once script that uses that data to create the `<animate>` elements you want, based on the fill of the elements. You can view this example live at http://phrogz.net/svg/change-color-on-hover.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:y="yasashiku" viewBox="0 0 240 150">
  <title>Change Color on Hover</title>
  <style>
    circle { stroke:black; stroke-width:2px }
    circle:not([fill]) { fill:purple }
  </style>
  <circle cx="50"  cy="50"  r="40" fill="red"    y:hoverAnimFillTo="blue"  y:hoverAnimDur="0.3s" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" fill="red"    y:hoverAnimFillTo="green" y:hoverAnimDur="1s" />
  <circle cx="150" cy="42"  r="40" fill="orange" y:hoverAnimFillTo="yellow" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="40"               y:hoverAnimFillTo="steelblue" />
  <script>
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        y   = 'yasashiku';
    for (var i=els.length;i--;){
      var fillColor = els[i].getAttributeNS(y,'hoverAnimFillTo');
      if (fillColor){
        var dur = els[i].getAttributeNS(y,'hoverAnimDur') || '0.1s';
        createOn(els[i],'animate',{
          begin:'mouseover',
          attributeType:'CSS', attributeName:'fill',
          to:fillColor,
          dur:dur, fill:'freeze'
        });
        createOn(els[i],'animate',{
          begin:'mouseout',
          attributeType:'CSS', attributeName:'fill',
          to:els[i].getAttribute('fill') || computedStyle(els[i],'fill'),
          dur:dur, fill:'freeze'
        });
      }
    }
    function createOn(el,name,attrs){
      var e = el.appendChild(document.createElementNS(el.namespaceURI,name));
      for (var name in attrs) e.setAttribute(name,attrs[name]);
      return e;
    }
    function computedStyle(el,name){
      return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)[name];
    }
  </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks; any thoughts on how I could revert back without a priori knowledge of the initial color?

Comment: @yasashiku Personally, I'd just JS to either control the colors or (simpler) dynamically create the `<animate>` elements based on the attributes. If this is an option for you (if JS is available) and you need help with it, I can amend my answer with details.

Comment: …nevermind, I've created an example and edited the question anyhow. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: There are a few reasons I'm trying to avoid as much js as possible (I'm trying for a ridiculous level of MVC... where EVERYTHING graphical is strictly SVG), but I guess a little javascript is going to be unavoidable... it's going to complicate things downstream, but thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Use "values" and "KeyTimes" attributes  ?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red">
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" values="red;green;green;red" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" begin="mouseover" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="red" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```